# How to get Current User on Sharepoint List by JSON (Column Formatting)

Tags: json, sharepoint

I've created a list for my staff which gets updated every day with overtime shifts as they become available. The last column of that list has a "Request Shift" hyperlink which sends me an e-mail, letting me know they would like to fill that shift. Aside from the fact that it comes from that users e-mail, I would like to include their name in the body, but I can't find an automated way to pull that from Sharepoint. I've tried @Me, I've tried currentUser, get_loginName; I just can't make it work. Any advice appreciated.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "='mailto:' + join([$Co_x002d_ordinator.email], ';') + '?subject=OT Request- ' + join([$Position], ';') + ', ' + toLocaleDateString([$Shift_x0020_start]) + '&body=I would like to request the following overtime shift: ' + join([$Position], ';') + ' on ' + toLocaleDateString([$Shift_x0020_start]) + ' at ' + toLocaleTimeString([$Shift_x0020_start])"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Request shift"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@me` (lowercase).

> "@me"
>
> This will evaluate to the email address of the current logged in
> user.
>
> This field can be used to display the current user's email address,
> but more likely it will be used within conditions.

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#me

Below are some code examples from the page above:

Evaluates to none if `@me` is not equal to `[$Author.email]`, and evaluates to `''` otherwise:

```
=if(@me != [$Author.email], 'none', '')
```

Sets the color to red when it is equal to the current logged in user and blue otherwise:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.title",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@me == @currentField.email, 'red', 'blue')"
  }
}
```

Returns an array replacing @me with 'kaylat@contoso.com':

```
"txtContent":"=replace([$MultiUserField], @me, 'kaylat@contoso.com')"
```